# Как добавить эту функцию в данный React код?

Tags: reactjs

Как добавить эту функцию:

```
var timer;
timer=setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1);
}, 5000);
```

к этому React коду:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBmvje

у меня есть сейчас слайдер изображений, но изображения меняются только по нажатию на кнопку, а я хочу добавить эту функцию что б он работал автоматически.

А вот весь Javascript код откуда откуда я "одолжил" эту функцию, чтобы было понятно откуда взялась функция "plusSlides(1);" :

```
var timer;
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
timer=setInterval(function() {
  plusSlides(1);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const { length, [active]: slide } = items;
  setInterval(() => setActive(active === length -1 ? 0 : active + 1), 5000)
```

как-то так

Comment: setActive(active === length -1 ? 0 : active + 1) можете заменить на свою функцию